# Elasticsearch mapping to not index negatives numbers

Tags: java, indexing, elasticsearch, int, mapping

Is there a way to set up our elasticsearch mapping so that a field is excluded or nulled in the elasticsearch index if the field in the java object (an int) is -1?

Thanks in advance for any comments or answers.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at creating a [transform step in your mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-transform.html).  (You could have a script null out the value for negative numbers here)

Comment: Other changes in our project have meant we're now doing this in a completely different way, so I'm not going to be able to confirm that this works. Thanks for your answer, and sorry I won't be able to mark it as correct.